# Error installing MahApps.Metro "trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v3.5'"

Tags: wpf, windows

I'm trying to install MahApps.Metro http://mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro/ on my Visual Basic .NetFramework 3.5 project, but i have an error

```
Could not install package 'MahApps.Metro 0.10.0.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v3.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

I don't understand i already huild on .NetFramework 3.5 .. how can i solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems this library requires .NET 4+. Upgrade to a higher .NET version (4.0 or 4.5) and it should work.